# Get signalr connection id outside the context of a signalr call

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have a typical web api controller which is called from a jscript client. During a request is being handled by the server I want to send a message to a group of signalr clients, except the client that corresponds to the current web api http request.

How can I get that connection id at that moment that signalr context is not available?
Of course I can have the client send it explicitly with the rest of the parameters of the http request, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a more elegant way. The connection id is stored on the client and is usually passed up with every request made with the signalr client.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a library for making the gap between your backend service bus and SignalR more seamless, if you implemented it. You could do it like this, from your WebApi method

```
eventAggregator.Publish(new MyEvent(data));
```

And the MyEvent

```
public class MyEvent : Event 
{
   public MyEvent(Data data) 
   {
      this.PerformedBy = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
   }
}
```

Then create a Constraint handler for that Event

```
public class MyEventConstraint : EventConstraintHandler<Event>
{
   public bool Allow(MyEvent myEvent, username, dynamic constraint) 
   {
      return myEvent.PerformedBy != username;
   }
}
```

You can also make the MyEvent generic so that you can reuse it for all your entities

More info and how to set it up
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Beware that all clients belonging to said user will not get the event